# RegExp to find command line arguments

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qt4, qregexp

i am workin on a terminal program to execute applications on remote machines.
you can pass a command like in the windows cmd.exe like:

```
"C:\random Directory\datApplication.py" "validate" -r /c "C:\anotherDirectory"
```

to make that possible i have to deal with quoted text and parse the command and its arguments from that string.
in notepad++ i found a RegExp to patch them `(([^" \t\n]+)|("[^"]*"))+` and it works. in `Qt4.8.1` i tried:

```
static const QRegExp re("(([^\" \\t\\n]+)|(\"[^\"]*\"))+");
re.matchExact(str); // str is something like shown above
qDebug() << re.capturedTexts();
```

and this code only prints me 3 times the `"C:\random Directory\datApplication.py"` and nothing more.
it should print out every argument entered as a single object ...

what can i do to make it working?

SOLUTION: (thanks to Lindrian)

```
const QString testText = "\"C:\\random Directory\\datApplication.py\" \"validate\" -r /c \"C:\\anotherDirectory\"";
static const QRegExp re("([^\" \\t\\n]+|\"[^\"]*\")+");
int pos = 0;
while ((pos = re.indexIn(testText)) != -1) //-i indicates that nothing is found
{
    const int len = re.matchedLength();
    qDebug() << testText.mid(pos,len);
    pos += len;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTFY: `([^" \t\n]+|"[^"]*")`

(You were just overusing backrefs)

Make sure you're capturing all results.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. had to change some qt code as well to 'find' the matches correct as well.
awesome link btw, helps to understand a lot (and as a bloody beginner to regexp i can use it) ;)